# How to sum two manually entered numbers in cells A and B and output the result next to them in cell C automatically with excel-VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

Iam still quite new to excel-VBA and I would like to

> automatically sum two manually entered numbers in cells A10:A12 and B10:B12 and
>   give out the result in cell C without using the formula =SUM()

Thank you in advance!!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sum columns A and B into column C for each row in Target.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A10:B12")) Is Nothing Then
        On Error GoTo meh
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Dim t As Range
        For Each t In Intersect(Target, Range("A10:B12"))
            Cells(t.Row, "C") = Application.Sum(Cells(t.Row, "A"), Cells(t.Row, "B"))
        Next t
    End If

meh:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! How could you do this for the ranges A10:A12 and B10:B12? (see my edits above.